# ¿Cómo mostrar barra de progreso al sincronizar carpetas mediante `rsync` y `pv`?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, rsync

Estoy tratando de sincronizar dos carpetas con `rsync` el comando es el siguiente:

```
$ rsync -ruthv --stats --delete-before origen/ destino/
```

- `-r, recurse into directories`
- `-u, skip files that are newer on the receiver`
- `-t, preserve modification times`
- `-h, output numbers in a human-readable format`
- `-v, increase verbosity`
- `--delete-before, receiver deletes before xfer, not during`
- `--stats, give some file-transfer stats`

Durante la sincronización me interesa mostrar una barra de progreso sobre el total, y he encontrado `pv`.

Si redirijo la salida de `rsync` a `pv -lep -s numeroDeArchivosASincronizar`

- `-l, Instead of counting bytes, count lines (newline characters).`
- `-e, Turn the ETA timer on.`
- `-p, Turn the progress bar on.`
- `-s SIZE, Assume the total amount of data to be transferred is SIZE bytes when calculating percentages and ETAs.`

Quedaria algo así:

```
$ rsync -ruthv --stats --delete-before origen/ destino/ | pv -lep -s numeroDeArchivosASincronizar
```

Obtengo lo que necesito, pero me gustaría que `numeroDeArchivosASincronizar` se calculara automáticamente.

Para obtenerlo se me ocurre algo como:

```
$ find origen/ -type f | wc -l
```

La cuestión es que no se como unir los 4 comandos (o las 2 parejas de comandos).

> **Nota** no estoy interesado en usar `awk` ni en un `bash` script, quiero usar pipes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
$ rsync -ruthv --stats --delete-before origen/ destino/ | pv -lep -s $(find origen/ -type f | wc -l)
```

Una expresión encerrada entre paréntesis y precedida de dolar, así: `$(expr)` se ejecuta como "sub-comando" y la salida estándar que ese subcomando produzca, se sustituye en lugar de la expresión `$(expr)`.

También se puede encerrar la expresión entre "backticks", es decir, `` `expr` `` en lugar de `$(expr)`, pero este uso [se considera casi depreciado](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/40596).

Comment: se usa `$()` en todos y de hecho el backtick está [prácticamente deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/40596) en todas las shell, entre otros motivos porque no permite anidar.

Comment: @fedorqui Además de ser un infierno de escribir en markdown! :-D Gracias por la corrección. Actualizaré la respuesta

Comment: Jajaja ahí le diste, el uso del bakctick en markdown es la parte más complicada

Comment: Muy interesante la respuesta @abulafia y la aclaración @fedorqui. Una consulta mas, ¿seria posible poner `origen/` una sola vez? Lo digo porque es una ruta bastantes larga

Comment: puedes hacer `ORIGEN=origen/; rsync ... $ORIGEN destino/ | pv -lep  $(find $ORIGEN -type f|wc -l)`